# Closure passed to array_filter reseting external variable passed using the "use" keyword

Tags: php

if I alter `$resultado_frontend` using `array_filter` it only changes it inside the function, if try to access `$resultado_frontend` after `array_filter` it is an empty array.

```
$resultado_frontend = [];

   $contas_b2w = array_filter($contas->toArray(), function($conta) use($id_admin, $resultado_frontend, $json_tiao) {

        if($conta['id_mkt'] == 3){

                $sku_existe = Anuncio::where([['id_admin', $id_admin], ['conta_id', $conta['id']]])->where('json_jcontrole->sku',  $json_tiao['sku'])->first();

                if($sku_existe){            

                    $resultado_frontend[] = ["essa conta já possui o sku cadastrado para este marketplace"];
                   dd($resultado_frontend); // here the string is inserted into the array


                }else{

                    return $conta;
                }

        }

    });

   dd($resultado_frontend); //If a remove the "dd" inside the closure and let  code reach this "dd", the array will be empty. How can I get around this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the overall goal is, so there may be a better way to do it, but if you want to modify `$resultado_frontend` inside the closure, you need to `use` a reference to it or it will be passed into the closure by value.

```
... use($id_admin, &$resultado_frontend, $json_tiao) { ...
```